# Run karate test from VS Code ReferenceError: "_$vaultInfo" is not defined

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, karate

I'm trying to run a karate test in VS Code. Developers who work on the project have their own setup with mvn and intellij, but I'm hoping to be able to run only the karate tests from VS Code as I don't have a mvn, IntelliJ set up.

In the background of many of the features there is this var:
* def url= _$vaultInfo.url

This comes from the karate-config.js:
`function fn() { // removing confidential stuff, hopefully irrelevant var pathToVaultfeature = 'file:' + karate.properties['user.dir'] + '/src/test/features/common/vault.feature'; var responseData= karate.callSingle(pathToVaultfeature, config); config._$vaultInfo= responseData.vaultInfo; return config; }`

Getting this error:
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "_$vaultInfo" is not defined

- .:program(Unnamed:1)

Am I supposed to point to the karate-config.js file anywhere in vs code. Looks like it's not getting picked up. I can run the basic getting started example from github without a problem.

Tried printing out this variable and trying to test whether karate-config.js is even getting picked up. No luck. Also tried using different runner, mvn or gradle instead of bundled. But that's not what looking to do even if I could get those working. I'm expecting there's a simple way to get up and running with just VSCode and the karate plugin to run my existing tests.

Comment: please refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/14 - if you are still stuck please provide a minimal example so we can replicate and fix it

Comment: Thanks Peter. The link you provided showed me the way:)